# How to declare a variable with class name string in c#

Tags: c#, types, typeof

when I receive a parameter which has a class name, how can I declare a proper variable with the class name? For example, if I have a method as follows:

```
public void foo(string class_name)
{
    object var1 = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(class_name));
}
```

`CreateInstance()` returns object. But I'd like to cast the object type to the `class_name_type` as follows.

```
class_name_type var1 = (class_name_type)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(class_name));
```

How can I declare `var1` as a `class_name_type` correctly?

Comment: Casting just changes the compile-time reference you have. It doesn't convert the type (it's already the type you created). So unless you have *compile-time* information about the type, there's no meaning in casting it. That's saying nothing about Generics.

Comment: You can't declare that variable correctly, that has to be done at compile time. Since you only know the type at runtime, you can't do it compile time. **Why** do you want to declare it with the right type at compile time?

Comment: If you have `class_name_Type` available at compile time (which is necessary to get your last code snippet to compile), why use this at all?  Can't you just actually construct `var1` from the class' constructor(s)?

Comment: Use common interface if you have access to implementation. Othewise use dynamic but it is not safe.

Comment: There are hundreds of code tables and correspondingly declared model classes.
In order to maintain these, I displayed the table names in the DataGridView, and when the user selects one code table, I want to display the contents in another DataGridView and then add or update records. By the way, I wanted to find a way to handle it dynamically because it requires hundreds of case statements to be processed at compile time.

Comment: That comment should be [edit]ed into the question. That's the real problem you're trying to solve. Anyway, you need to use reflection to examine the properties of the type that's selected.

Comment: As @madreflection said you need to [edit] question into "How to do {what you want to achive}, I tried {that impossible approach of using type unknown at compile  time}" to be answerable... At this point question is duplicate of one of many similar questions which all essentially have the same answer "not possible, for each particular case there is alternative you can use".